# outlook-addin Office.AttachmentContent interface not working

Tags: outlook-addin, email-attachments, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In my outlook-addin I am trying to get the attachments from the active e-mail message.

I copy pasted the example from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-preview

exact example code:

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var options = {asyncContext: {currentItem: item}};
item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback);

function callback(result) {
    if (result.value.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < result.value.length ; i++) {
            result.asyncContext.currentItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(result.value[i].id, handleAttachmentsCallback);
        }
    }
}

function handleAttachmentsCallback(result) {
    // Parse string to be a url, an .eml file, a base64-encoded string, or an .icalendar file.
    switch (result.value.format) {
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64:
            // Handle file attachment.
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml:
            // Handle email item attachment.
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.ICalendar:
            // Handle .icalender attachment.
            break;
        case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Url:
            // Handle cloud attachment.
            break;
        default:
            // Handle attachment formats that are not supported.
    }
}
```

yet upon addin launch I get an error saying `item.getAttachmentsAsync` is not a function.

I looked in the API docs for help but can't find any information on this issue.

Any clues? maybe you encountered this problem too?

Comment: Are you in read mode? getAttachmentsAsync is a compose mode only API.

Comment: then which method should I use to get the attachments while reading an e-mail item? I saw in the message object that there seems to be a method `getAttachments` but it's not working too.

Comment: After your hint about getAttachmentsAsync being a compose modeo nly API I found that in read mode you can access the attachments array like so: Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments <array of objects>. There if it is of type MailboxEnums.AttachmentType.Cloud then you can access it's url. How to go about  for example having a pdf attached to an e-mail and I want to pass that pdf through my addin to my application servers.

Comment: Please refer to the link about attaching a file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

Comment: Also, you can take a look at `getAttachmentContentAsync`. Sample code here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-1.8. This API allows you to retrieve the contents of the attachment (in different formats), and then you can send that to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @outlook-add-ins-team-msft : getAttachmentsAsync is a compose mode only API.

Here is a follow up question using the right methods from the api.

[Office addin getAttachementContentAsync failed to load CORS issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758519/office-addin-getattachementcontentasync-failed-to-load-cors-issues)