# "TypeError: item.getAttachmentsAsync is not a function" Outlook add-in office-js with Vue

Tags: vue.js, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've been following the tutorial from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#getAttachmentContentAsync_attachmentId__options__callback_ to try and get attachments from an outlook email for an Office add-in from the Taskpane. I am doing this from the Read scenario not the Compose scenario which is supposed to be available from Requirements Set 1.8.

I have updated the Requirements Set in the manifest to 1.8

```
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
```

As well as updating the Version Overrides Requirements Set

```
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.8">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
```

In my Vue file this is my code:

```
mounted()
{
    this.loading = true;
    var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

    console.log(item);
    var options = {asyncContext: {currentItem: item}};
    item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, callback);

    function callback(result)
    {
        console.log("inside callback");
        console.log(result.value.length)
        if (result.value.length > 0)
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++)
            {
                result.asyncContext.currentItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(result.value[i].id, handleAttachmentsCallback);
                console.log("function callback");
                console.log(result.value[i].id);
            }
        }
    }

    function handleAttachmentsCallback(result)
    {
        console.log("item attachment handler");
        // Parse string to be a url, an .eml file, a base64-encoded string, or an .icalendar file.
        switch (result.value.format)
        {
            case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Base64:
                // Handle file attachment.
                console.log("got base 64");
                console.log("result ----------" + result.value);
                _this.sendRequest(result.value)
                break;
            case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Eml:
                // Handle email item attachment.
                break;
            case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.ICalendar:
                // Handle .icalender attachment.
                break;
            case Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentContentFormat.Url:
                // Handle cloud attachment.
                break;
            default:
            // Handle attachment formats that are not supported.
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following Error:

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: item.getAttachmentsAsync is not a function"

> vue.js:1897 TypeError: item.getAttachmentsAsync is not a function
> at VueComponent.mounted (getAttachments.vue:265)
> at click (getAttachments.vue?ccdf:99)
> at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.js:1863)
> at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.js:2188)
> at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.js:7547)

I have tried all of these and none have resolved the problem, I even tried to get the attachment data manually with no success. Because it shows the attachment data in the console but it doesn't go further due to the error.

[outlook-addin Office.AttachmentContent interface not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057723/outlook-addin-office-attachmentcontent-interface-not-working)

[How get attachments in outlook plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679858/how-get-attachments-in-outlook-plugin)

Thank you, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#getAttachmentsAsync_options__callback_) is only available in Compose mode. If you are working from the Read scenario, you can use the [attachments property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#property-details) on the Office.MessageRead interface to get the attachments on the item.

For example:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments[0].id
```

will be the attachment id of the first attachment on the item.

Comment: I'm confused with the getAttachmentsAsync, in Microsoft Documentation they mention that you can use in READ and also in COMPOSE.
¿how can I get the content of each attachment ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - is there a way to get the attachment content in read?

Comment: You can get the attachment content via the getAttachmentContentAsync API in Message Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#getAttachmentContentAsync_attachmentId__options__callback_